# I need to read new line characters in a file

Tags: c, file

Suppose a text file has `hello\n stack overflow \n` in a file, the output should be `2` since there are 2 `\n` sequences. Instead, I am getting one as the answer. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    FILE                *fp = fopen("sample.txt", "r");    /* or use fopen to open a file */
    int                 c;              /* Nb. int (not char) for the EOF */
    unsigned long       newline_count = 1;

        /* count the newline characters */
    while ( (c=fgetc(fp)) != EOF ) {
        if ( c == '\n' )
            newline_count++;
        putchar(c);
    }

    printf("\n  %lu newline characters\n ", newline_count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ive posted my attempt, give me a hand here. Obviously there is a problem.

Comment: The problem is, I want to specifically count using \n as the text, not as an enter, but as \n\, so the output for your file should be one.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe the question is basic, but that doesn't mean one can say that **it should not be upvoted**. At least he stated his problem clearly, and posted whatever he has tried? Much better question than many we receive daily here on SO..

Comment: @Krishnabhadra Did you see it before it was edited? It was a mess.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Check before it was edited, it had problems. And yes, it was upvoted before it was edited, and I came along and downvoted it, and then Scott edited it.

Comment: Guys, lets focus on the problem and my confusion

Comment: Yes, his code was not formatted correctly. And he is not the only user  who struggle with code formatting here. That is why others have the provisions to edit, so that questions like this can be made good. If the question is poor even after editing, or formatting is not the only problem with it, then there is a problem. But it is not the case here IMHO.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra Maybe someone should look into clearing up the confusion with code formatting? Maybe some auto-code-recognition?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: While most of you are bickering for no reason, Benji actually helped me. Thank you BenjiWiebe

Comment: @user1888502 Some of us can actually multi-task (bicker *and* help). I managed it quite well, don't you think? ;)

Comment: @BenjiWiebe: I can see that you're relatively new to the site, so I'd like to remind you of the FAQ: "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an **egregiously** sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."  Emphasis mine.  Your help is appreciated, but complaining about upvotes to questions that really only have some minor formatting problems is **not constructive** and please refrain from doing so in the future.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe And full information is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down). And user1888502 it is good that you got your answer. But remember stackoverflow is a community of like minded people, and it is important that someone contributing here should know what he is doing and how it should be done.. We were not bickering along, but were helping someone who has come forward to help the community...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    FILE                *fp = fopen("sample.txt", "r");    /* or use fopen to open a file */
    int                 c, lastchar = 0;              /* Nb. int (not char) for the EOF */
    unsigned long       newline_count = 0;

        /* count the newline characters */
    while ( (c=fgetc(fp)) != EOF ) {
        if ( c == 'n' && lastchar == '\\' )
            newline_count++;
        lastchar = c; /* save the current char, to compare to next round */
        putchar(c);
    }

    printf("\n  %lu newline characters\n ", newline_count);
    return 0;
}
```

Really, a literal `\n` is two characters (a string), not just one. So you cannot simply compare it as though it was a character.

**EDIT**
Since `\n` is two characters, the `\` and the `n`, we must remember the last character we read in, and check if the current character is an `n` and the previous character is a `\`. If both tests are true, that means we have located the sequence `\n` in the file.

Comment: I am putting \n, since that is what I want and need. So pretty much, Benji\n\Wiebe\n the output should be 2, not one. Even though it's one one line.

Comment: Thank you BenjiWiebe, I am waiting.

Comment: @user1888502 And try it again with http://www.benjiwiebe.com/sample.txt it should output `3`.

Comment: Thanks!!!. Last question, Can you explain your logic in the if statement, the if (c=='n')and why you are storing the lastChar.

Comment: @user1888502 so in other words your question has nothing to do with newline characters :)

Comment: What if instead of /n it was \r\n?

Comment: @BenjieWiebe what if a new line was represented as \r\n instead of \n

Comment: @user1888502 It would work anyway. `\r\n` ends with `\n`, so it would detect the trailing `\n`.